# Rearrange list in ADB DEVICES

Tags: android, adb

When I type "adb devices", it will list:

```
emulator-5554 device <-- this is emulator
0123456789ABCDEF device <-- this is my smartphone
```

A software called ShareKM will automatically detect the first device in the list thus will cause an error "Android app is not installed".

So what I did is, close the emulator, adb kill-server, adb start-server, launch ShareKM, launch emulator. If I "adb devices" it will be:

```
0123456789ABCDEF device <-- this is my smartphone
emulator-5554 device <-- this is emulator
```

But this is too hustle.

Is there a command to rearrange the list without killing or restart emulator? Lets say "adb put 0123456789ABCDEF to 1"

Comment: This link gives you all with adb. [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)